# Should i use primary key of DB as reference for my app?

Tags: android, sql-server, database, wcf, primary-key

As requested by my teaching professor of "Database Basics", I need to build a solid software project to get access to my final exam of this teaching.

My thoughts were to build an application (let's say a simple android application with a map) that would communicate with a WCF service(attached, obviously, to the DB i need to implement).

Now, here's the (probably dumb) question: it's ok if i reference *directly* my rows with the primary key?
Following the example with the map, the service would give me a list of "markers" (which they would populate the map) with a ID each.
It's generally safe to exchange the primary key of a table (in this case, the ID) for an easier use to the clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's technically possible to pass primary keys through different modules of your system, but from a software engineering point of view, It's totally discouraged.
There's a famous concept called **Layered Programming**, which you should have heard of it for sure. 
The general purpose of this concept is the separation of functionalities or **Loosely Coupling** and **ease of maintenance and further developments management.**
The concept introduces 3 general layers for any software solution (mostly data-oriented) :
 DAL (Data Access Layer), BLL(Business Logic Layer) and PL (Presentation Layer), which refer to 3 different aspect of the software solution.

Since you're to implement a college project, you don't have to go through the process of layered development, necessarily. But I recommend you to just try a simple methodology of this concept, because it really helps to build a robust foundation and dramatically decreases the rate of errors and code correction and adjustment efforts.

Also , exchanging primary key or any database-native data is totally discouraged.So try to exchange some other identifier. You can try to build an arbitrary identifier for each map marker, based on the primary key.